# Setting up redirects from routes.php

Tags: plugin-development, url, routes, redirect

I have a "/5minutes" url in routes.php and people keep typing in "fiveminutes". Is there a way to call a 301 redirect directly in routes.php or would I need to set up an action in my plugin (or alternatively mess with server settings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try and avoid the `routes.php` route (pun intended).  There isn't any need to get Craft involved in a redirect when your web server (Apache?) can handle it much faster.

If you're using Apache, then adding something like this to your public `.htaccess` file should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^fiveminutes$ /5minutes [NC,R=301,L]
```

**Update:**

Missed the part where you said this was in a plugin.  In that case you'd want to setup something like this in your main plugin's class file:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'fiveminutes' => array('action' => 'myPluginController/fiveMinuteRedirect'),
   );
}
```

Then from your `MyPluginController.php` class have an `actionFiveMinuteRedirect()` method that simply did a permanent [redirect](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#redirect-detail):

```
`$this->redirect('5minutes', true, 301);`
```

Comment: He did mention that it's in his plugin. If he intends for his plugin to be portable, then .htaccess isn't going to solve his problem. But, if it's a one-off business logic plugin, then I fully agree that .htaccess is the way to go.

Comment: Doh! Totally missed the plugin part.  Will update my answer.